# Where should I put my CSS and JS files for Spring MVC?

Tags: css, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I'm having a problem with the templates used for Spring MVC, because it can't find the CSS files defined in href

[image: Spring tools]

Comment: Where's your `tagIndex.html` file?

Comment: In the folder templates

Comment: And do you use some kind of template engine such as Thymeleaf maybe?

Answer (score 0):

In your spring web config file set proper path like :
(presuming java based)

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");

}
```

all files under resources will work.

Comment: Sorry but i dont lnow where i can find this config file. You can help me?

Comment: First learn spring MVC properly. https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/spring-mvc-full-java-based-config/